# How to configure scheduler-locking gdb option in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb

I can add additional argument from `launch.json` to gdb by [miDebuggerArgs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_midebuggerargs)

Something like this:

```json
"MIMode": "gdb",
"miDebuggerArgs": "-ex 'help set scheduler-locking'",
```

works as expected

But why this one doesn't work?

```json
"miDebuggerArgs": "-ex 'show scheduler-locking'",
```

Also doesn't work `set scheduler-locking step`

The option [setupCommands](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_setupcommands) gives me only errors:
*Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-interpreter-exec console "set scheduler-locking step"". Target 'None' cannot support this command.* It doesn't look useful

Is there any other option to setting up `set scheduler-locking step` before debug is paused on breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Create a file somewhere, I suggest `gdb.conf` in your workspace root. Refer to that file in your launch config in `.vscode/launch.json`:

`"miDebuggerArgs": "-x '${workspaceFolder}/gdb.conf'"`

In the file, define hooks for post run and post attach (hooks described [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Hooks.html)):

```
echo Adding hooks for stop to "set scheduler-locking step"\n
define hookpost-run
  set scheduler-locking step
end
define hookpost-attach
  set scheduler-locking step
end
```

(If using GDB directly instead of via VS Code, you can use `gdb -x gdb.conf`)

### Explanation

The `Target 'None' cannot support this command.` error happens when you attempt to `set scheduler-locking step` with no target. If you run bare `gdb` in a terminal and then the command (or include it with `-ex`), you'll get the same error. (Aside: it is possible to provide it with `-ex` or run early on, in this situation, if starting a process or attaching to one with `-p`).

VS Code's MI debugger starts GDB, runs all the setupCommands and then attaches, meaning that it will always run those commands early. Likewise if you try to supply with `-ex`.

Using the technique from [this feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2745#issuecomment-1066143056), you can create a hook and have it run the `set` command then. The linked comment is slightly wrong so I won't directly quote.

(See TL;DR)

This tells GDB to create a hook to run after `run` and `attach`. You may also need `target hookpost-remote` instead if you use remote GDB (not tested).

Thus, when the hooks run, GDB is ready for the `set` command and it succeeds.

*Note:* do not include the command outside of the hook, because if it fails it will cause GDB to stop executing the commands in the file.

### Background

*Hopefully this will make it easier to find this answer from searching for strange step over/next behaviour in VS Code/GDB*

GDB halts all threads on break, but releases them all when you continue or step the program. The command `set scheduler-locking step` tells GDB to lock all threads except the active thread when performing a step command (e.g. `step`/`next`). This means its much more intuitive when asking to step to the next line in GDB or an editor, as other threads won't interrupt.

Comment: (Some credit to my colleague, who helped with solving this for our project :) )

Comment: Many thanks, great solution. It works as you noted except for one thing. With `${workspaceFolder}` it doesn't work. Command `"miDebuggerArgs": "-x '~/gdb.conf'"` works for me

Comment: Thanks :)

Judging by the path you've given your config is in your home directory rather than workspace folder, so it naturally wouldn't work. Doing it your way is fine though, I can see one wanting to reuse the same file across multiple workspaces. :) Please could you mark the answer as accepted (looks like you upvoted at least :P )

Comment: My mistake. Let `${workspaceFolder}` == `~/a/b`
`"miDebuggerArgs": "-x '${workspaceFolder}/gdb.conf'"` - does not work,
but
`"miDebuggerArgs": "-x '~/a/b/gdb.conf'"` - works properly.